# No puedo abrir mi solucion de Visual Studio, "El valor no esta dentro del intervalo esperado"

Tags: c#, visual-studio

me encontraba desarrollando un sistema de ventas usando C# con Visual Studio.NET 2022, sin embargo, el dia de hoy, al intentar abrir la solucion, me salia un error que decia "**no se pudo abrir SistemaVentas desea quitar las referencias a el en la lista de elementos recientes?**", posteriormente trate de abrirlo accediendo directamente al archivo de la solucion(*.sln), y me salio un error que decia "**El valor no esta dentro del intervalo esperado**", esto me parece raro, porque ayer si podia acceder y cuando trate de acceder hoy, ocurria esto, **no hice ningua modificacion a ningun archivo ni a la configuracion**.
[image: Me aparece esto]

No puedo colocar ningun fragmento del codigo del proyecto, porque como ya mencione, no hay manera de acceder en este momento.

Espero que exista una solucion a este problema porque es un proyecto importante y tenia una avance considerable, por lo que empezarlo desde 0 no estaria bien.

OJO: Aún no soy 100% experto en el tema, si mi pregunta es "absurda" por favor sean respetuosos, realmente necesito ayuda porque no puedo perder este proyecto.

Actualizacion: Volvi a intentar abrir la solucion y me aparecio un nuevo error: "No se puede completar la operacion, el parametro no es correcto."

Actualizacion:

Este es el codigo de el archivo .sln:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.3.32825.248
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CapaPresentacion", "CapaPresentacion\CapaPresentacion.csproj", "{591B8BA5-9959-4BA0-9001-CE5CF267B281}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CapaEntidad", "CapaEntidad\CapaEntidad.csproj", "{56427434-4E03-4C59-9E52-C0953E9243C0}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CapaNegocio", "CapaNegocio\CapaNegocio.csproj", "{9994D12B-BB3A-4E68-BD92-6CCF82CDFEDE}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "CapaDatos", "CapaDatos\CapaDatos.csproj", "{B2B8CEF4-3491-4872-A086-17CD15F91419}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {591B8BA5-9959-4BA0-9001-CE5CF267B281}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {591B8BA5-9959-4BA0-9001-CE5CF267B281}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {591B8BA5-9959-4BA0-9001-CE5CF267B281}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {591B8BA5-9959-4BA0-9001-CE5CF267B281}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {56427434-4E03-4C59-9E52-C0953E9243C0}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {56427434-4E03-4C59-9E52-C0953E9243C0}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {56427434-4E03-4C59-9E52-C0953E9243C0}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {56427434-4E03-4C59-9E52-C0953E9243C0}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {9994D12B-BB3A-4E68-BD92-6CCF82CDFEDE}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {9994D12B-BB3A-4E68-BD92-6CCF82CDFEDE}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {9994D12B-BB3A-4E68-BD92-6CCF82CDFEDE}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {9994D12B-BB3A-4E68-BD92-6CCF82CDFEDE}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {B2B8CEF4-3491-4872-A086-17CD15F91419}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {B2B8CEF4-3491-4872-A086-17CD15F91419}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {B2B8CEF4-3491-4872-A086-17CD15F91419}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {B2B8CEF4-3491-4872-A086-17CD15F91419}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {24974257-6EEC-4C62-9CA2-6A39C6591454}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: abrilo con notepad a ver q tiene

Comment: Hola, cual de todos los archivos debería abrir? Además, hay algo que no comprendo, porque ayer si funcionaba bien, y de la noche a la mañana ya no se puede abrir sin que haya modificado absolutamente nada?

Comment: el archivo .sln es de texto fijate si hay algo raro ahi, podes probar mover la carpeta oculta `.vs` si es que existe. microsoft a veces hace eso de updatear sin avisar ( y muchas veces les falla el asunto ) entre ayer y hoy hubo un patch de .net tal vez haya sido eso. podes probar recompilar el sln desde linea de comando a ver si da un mensaje mas claro

Comment: Disculpa la ignorancia, cual es el comando que debo usar para recopilar el archivo sln desde línea de comando?

Comment: Fuera del tema: no hay preguntas absurdas en este sitio. Solo preguntas abiertas y preguntas cerradas. Las preguntas abiertas pueden terminar cerradas si no se pueden responder o no se ajustan al sitio. [Más información](/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Comment: opcion 1 usando `MSBuild` : busca el `MSBuild.exe` que corresponda a tu proyecto en `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework *** \ v*** \MSBuild.exe` , por ejemplo `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe` seguido del path completo al solution por ejemplo `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe C:\work\CS\_sources\mods\DuplicateAssemblyScanner\DuplicateAssemblyScanner.sln`

Comment: opcion 2 usando `devenv` : con los paths configurados y dentro de la carpeta del proyecto por ejemplo `devenv DuplicateAssemblyScanner.sln /build `  ( proba con opciones tipo  `/build Debug`, `/rebuild Release` , `/build "Debug|x64"` etc )

Comment: Recompile el .sln usando MSBuild, no me dio ningun mensaje de error, pero sigo sin poder abrirlo, por otro lado, abri el archivo .sln con Notepad++, acabo de actualizar este post agregando el contenido de ese archivo.

Comment: Si es un proyecto de .NET Core (No Net Framework) puedes compilarlo por linea de comandos con `dotnet build`. SI es NET Framork utiliza MSBuild. Si compila correctamente, el problema está con tu instalación de Visual Studio.

Comment: Es un proyecto de .Net framework, como mencioné lo recompile con MSBuild y no salió ningún mensaje de error. Cuál podría ser el problema con la instalación de Visual Studio?

Comment: Por último, si nada te ayuda puedes copiar tus archivos .cs de tu carpeta de proyecto a un nuevo proyecto en blanco al menos así no empezaras de 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regularmente esto sucede porque se daña el directorio .vs ubicado dentro de la carpeta del proyecto.

En mi caso sucedio ya que el equipo se encontraba suspendido y hubo una falla en la energia electrica y el equipo se apago repentinamente.

Para solucionarlo realizar los siguientes pasos:

1. Deben configurar el explorador de windows para poder ver los archivos ocultos.
2. Ir a la carpeta donde tienen el proyecto por ejemplo c:\miproyecto
3. Dentro de la carpeta del proyecto podran ver un directorio oculto llamado ".vs"
4. Eliminar el directorio (pueden hacer un respaldo antes de eliminarlo si gustan).
5. Abrir nuevamente la solucion (miproyecto.sln).
6. Visual Studio creará nuevamente la carpeta .vs con la nueva configuracion.

Espero les funcione!